# batch setlocal analogue in Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-5.0

Imagine that we have such a batch script

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd C:\Users\user\Work\SomeWorkingDirectory
endlocal
```

So, if such script will be started, for example, from `C:\Users\user\`, then after script execution current directory in terminal still will be `C:\Users\user`, not `C:\Users\user\Work\SomeWorkingDirectory`.

So, the question is: are there any `setlocal` / `endlocal` analogues in Powershell? Googled it, can't find.

Comment: `pushd`/`popd`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell's scoping rules are different from those of WinBatch.

For most variables, they will only be visible within the script or function in which they are defined. Environment variables, e.g., `$env:Path` can be modified, but the modification will only persist for the duration of the PowerShell session. For persistent changes, and more information about environment variables, see [`about_Environment_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-5.0).

For paths, as you seem to be asking, you can use the [`Push-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/push-location?view=powershell-5.0)  and [`Pop-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/pop-location?view=powershell-5.0) cmdlets (by default, aliased to `pushd` and `popd`, respectively).